# Submit App created with SDK 6 but partly developed with iOS and SDK 7

Tags: xcode, sdk, ios7

I started to t work on an App using SDK 6 and then switched to iOS 7 Beta and Xcode 5, but Apps *created* with Beta SDKs cannot be submitted to the App Store.

Does this also apply to the project I started with Xcode 4.6 and SDK 6? If so, is there any way to *go back* like simply using Xcode 4.6 and iOS 6 again (I won't be using any iOS 7 APIs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to code-sign and archive from the iOS 6 SDK. I have done this back-tracking before and it required some work with storyboards.

Assuming you have both versions of Xcode installed on your machine, you can try simply opening your Xcode 5 project in Xcode 4.6. Like I said, however, when doing this I had trouble with a storyboard, but you can address that issue if you reach it.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was exactly the information I needed!